# Fetch Firebase data with For loop in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am trying to fetch specific Firebase data with a for loop but it gives me this error: "'ListenerRegistration' cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol 'View' because 'View' has static requirements". The Code runs if the ZStack{}.onAppear() function is called. How can I change that?

```
ForEach(self.allFriends, id: \.id) { friend in
            Firestore.firestore().collection(friend.email+"-TodayCal").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("error fetching: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }

                    let name = documents.map { $0["nameOfFriend"] }
                    print(name)
                    self.allFriendsCal.removeAll()
                    for i in 0..<name.count {
                        self.allFriendsCal.append(AllFriendsCal(id: UUID(uuidString: documents[i].documentID) ?? UUID(), name: name[i] as? String ?? "Failed to get Name"))
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: `ForEach` is a container for SwiftUI views. Move all that `Firestore` code into view model.

Comment: This `.collection(friend.email+"-TodayCal")` may become problematic as email can contain characters that cannot be used as collection names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` is a `View` type, which takes in other `View`s in the function builder. You can achieve what you want by calling the Firebase collection in `onAppear()` or wherever else you already have `allFriends` populated and iterating through the results like so:

```
.onAppear {
    for friend in self.allFriends {
        Firestore.firestore().collection(friend.email+"-TodayCal").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("error fetching: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            let name = documents.map { $0["nameOfFriend"] }
            print(name)
            self.allFriendsCal.removeAll()
            for i in 0..<name.count {
                self.allFriendsCal.append(AllFriendsCal(id: UUID(uuidString: documents[i].documentID) ?? UUID(), name: name[i] as? String ?? "Failed to get Name"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user6825883 I like this answer but I am questioning hitting firebase in a tight loop like that within a view (a UI element) is going to cause issues. You would typically gather data and populate a dataSource within the Controller of MVC, not the view. You're also adding an observer on every friend `.addSnapshotListener` so any time anything in one of those friends documents changes, the code in that closure is going to fire. Are you sure you want to do that?